# How to register normal MVC controller when using Umbraco 12

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, umbraco12

I'm trying to register a normal ASP.NET Core 7 MVC route with Umbraco 12. This controller should be responsible for PayPal payment process and it's not related to Umbraco at all.

I tried to register the controller this way:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseUmbraco()
        .WithMiddleware(u =>
        {
            u.UseBackOffice();
            u.UseWebsite();
        })
        .WithEndpoints(u =>
        {
            u.UseInstallerEndpoints();
            u.UseBackOfficeEndpoints();
            u.UseWebsiteEndpoints();
            u.EndpointRouteBuilder.MapControllerRoute(
                "PayPal",
                "paypal/{action}",
                new { controller = "PayPal", action = "Index" });
        });
}
```

But when I try to access the endpoint, Umbraco returns my "not found" page.

Comment: If you are asking about Umbraco 12, why is this tagged `umbraco8` and `umbraco9`?

Comment: Changed thank you!

Comment: Actually, Umbraco expects controllers to be registered as transient, meaning a new instance is created for each request. In your current code, you're only registering the route, but not the controller itself.

You can do like this : `public void Compose(Composition composition) {
  composition.Register<PayPalController>(Lifetime.Transient);
}`  Also Umbraco uses a base URL for its routes by default. This means that your PayPal route needs to be prefixed with the Umbraco base URL.

Comment: Thank you, I should read about compositions in Umbraco 12.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron can u explain a little more, I didn't saw a IComposer to have method "Compose" with parameter of type "Composition".